# Error adding one content type. Bundle missing in term references

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes, entities

I've got a problem on a Drupal 7.14 site when trying to add a new node to only one content type.

I get the following error message in the log:

```
EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type taxonomy_term. in entity_extract_ids() (line 7389 of /homepages/33/d169792374/htdocs/sites/yourfutureinautomotive.com/includes/common.inc).
```

I've tried the fixes outlined [here](http://drupal.org/node/1270340) as well as removing modules one by one and I'm not getting anywhere.

I've even reverted back to 7.8 to make sure I was on the same version as other people who were having the issue.

I'm open to any ideas or troubleshooting hints.

Ta

**EDIT**

As per @mojzis suggestion below I used the Devel dpm function. The following was output:

[image]

**EDIT 2**

vid: 14 is the problem. There is no vocab with vid of 14. Trying to hunt down a reference to it anywhere but not having much luck.

Comment: Are you creating the node programmatically? Could you post your code?

Comment: No this is all through the admin.

Comment: try adding dpm($entity) before the exception to see which one it was, and whether it has a vocabulary_machine_name set.

Comment: @mojzis - I've tried this, it's giving me a vocab machine name of null.

Comment: it looks weird altogether :) there is no tid ? And BTW, the vid should refer to some term, not taxonomy.  So, to recap the situation:  you have a  field which is setu[ as a term reference, right ? And what are the settings there ? Which vocab is selected ?  Is there any default value set ? What value do you provide when saving ? Does this happen when you set some value or when you set no value ?

Comment: Strangely enough, I added a vocab called Nothing with a VID of 14 and can now add content again which is really odd and not much help in terms of troubleshooting this but it seems to have worked.

Comment: sorry, vid does refer to vocabulary, you are right ... then i would think that there is a mistake in the settings of your field, did you check it ?

Comment: Yeah I've had a good look. The thing with it being a vid that doesn't exist is that it's hard to narrow down which field is misbehaving. I was hoping the terms that were being added would give me a club but nothing yet. For now I'll settle with the old "Working is better than perfect" mantra and try and come back to it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I'm going to answer this with that's solved the issue for me.

I got a bit desperate and was trying to hack common.inc in the core (may god have mercy on my soul), but after checking things out using the wonderful Devel module I just added in a test taxonomy vocabulary with a VID of 14. I can now add content again which is good, but am none the wiser as to the actual cause of the problem.

Interestingly the vocab as terms added to it when I add a new content of the type that was giving me trouble but they're blank. When I get a bit more time I'll try and troubleshoot this properly but if anyone else has the same issue, this is what solved it for me.

Comment: so, once you have some time :) try running dpm(field_info_fields()); in devel/php . the fields that are of interest to you have ['type'] = 'taxonomy_term_reference' and you should check their ['settings']['allowed_values'][0]['vocabulary'] - that holds the machine name of the vocabulary ... how it translates to a non-existent id is really interesting :)

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is most likely related to the Media module, and specifically this issue: '[Missing bundle property on entity of type file error](http://drupal.org/node/1266620)'. In your troubleshooting efforts, did you run across this info? A quick check to confirm if this is the culprit is to follow the step(s) outlined in [comment #5](http://drupal.org/node/1266620#comment-4938250).